# I turned my Python script into an executable. How can the program identify which directory it is in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, directory, executable

I have an executable that exports a CSV. I want the CSV to be exported to the same folder where the executable is kept.

Is there something I can put in the script so that, if the executable is moved to a different folder, the CSV will be saved in that new folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be on the save side you can make use of the pathlib module.

```
from pathlib import Path

path_script = Path(__file__)
path_csv = path_script.parent.joinpath('my_table.csv')

with open(path_csv, 'w') as csv:
   ...
```

Comment: you should add 'w' to the open, as the default is 'r'