# Why using crontab I get "-bash: Applications: command not found"?

Tags: python, bash, macos, cron

I'm trying to schedule a simple python script on MacOS using crontab. I have seen lot of guides and answers to other questions here in SO but still can't get my task to work. Actually I'm not so familiar with terminal and this kind of stuff but it didn't seem so difficult so I'm hoping to solve it.

I followed two different approaches.

First approach:

1. I use the command `crontab -e` on the terminal
2. In VIM I press I for Insert and paste the following:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python mypath/ap.py
```

3. Press "esc" and ":qw" to close VIM window.
4. `crontab -l` shows my cron entry as expected, BUT nothing happens from the script (it is supposed to create a txt file).

Second approach:

1. I paste this line in the terminal:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python mypath/ap.py >> mypath/MyCronLog.txt 2>&1
```

2. In this way I can see a txt file where I can read the log and eventual errors. MyCronLog.txt shows: `-bash: Applications: command not found` or `-bash: ap.py: command not found`.

My python script is located in a folder on my dekstop (I don't know if it matters).

Moreover I run my python script from terminal and it works perfectly.
Any suggestion is appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**
The path of my python script is the following:
/Users/myname/Desktop/ap/ap.py

**EDIT 2:**
"/opt/anaconda3/bin/python" in place of "/usr/bin/python" but nothing has changed.

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname for `mypath/ap.py`: `/Users/yourname/mypath/ap.py`

Comment: @Barmar I actually used an absolute pathname, sorry for have not specified that.

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? Replace `/usr/bin/python` with the output if they differ

Comment: Specify exactly what you are using for `mypath`.  My guess is that it contains the string 'Applications' and some components with whitespace.

Comment: @Frisk19 can you update the question to be correct (i.e. put `/Users/yourname/mypath`) so you don't have lots of make it absolute answers / comments.

Comment: When you try to run the command in Terminal, don't include the `* * * * *` part -- that tells cron when to run the command, and isn't part of the command. If you include those, each `*` will expand to a list of files and folders in the current directory, and if the first one happens to be named "Applications", it'll try to run that as the command name. But note that even running the command correctly in Terminal isn't a very good test, because cron executes things in a significantly different environment.

Comment: @kevinnls Yes they differed. And I tried to clean all versions I had; now I'm using what "which python?" suggests but nothing has changed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I edited my question, no Applications strings.

Comment: @GordonDavisson my goal is to schedule this python script.

Comment: @Frisk19 Users Desktop folders are considered "private", and software isn't allowed access to them unless [the user specifically grants access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers). It's possible to [grant access to cron](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402132/cronjobs-do-not-run), but I'd recommend moving the files (both script and log) to a public location instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I granted access to Terminal and cron! I will change that following your suggestion when I will be able to make work my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your python script. I guess the txt-file is created but in the wrong folder. When cron calls a python script, the working directory is NOT the directory of that script (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job)). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66804990/i-turned-my-python-script-into-an-executable-can-the-program-logic-identify-whi/66805083#66805083) for a workaround.

**EDIT:**

The behavior of your script *might* depend on the directory from which you call it (not an ideal way to write scripts).  When you are in `/Users/myname/Desktop/ap` and call `python ap.py`, this might lead to something different than calling `python ap/ap.py` from  `/Users/myname/Desktop`

You can verify this by calling this short script:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

I can imagine that your script crashes when called by cron while it works if you call it from the containing directory.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. But I mean, If I try to run my script from the terminal it's everything perfect and I can easily find my new file in the same folder. Even checking in other directories the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Frisk19 See my edit. Maybe you should provide us with the code of your python script.

Comment: i think there is a directory in your shell's PATH that isn't available in cron. this would explain its working from the Terminal but not from cron. this would also directly relate with a `command not found` error prefixed with the _script's filename_. compare the PATH variables. the cron version might be in the comments at the top of your crontab file. the shell one is accessible with `echo $PATH`. would also help if you can share the Python script

Comment: @Durtal Yes it is! I edited my question with the python script. So, when I'm in ```/Users/myname/Desktop/ap``` and call ```python ap.py```, it works perfectly. When I'm in ```/Users/myname/Desktop``` and call ```python ap/ap.py``` it doesn't work no more. I also call your script and this is what I got: ```/Users/myname/Desktop/ap```. Is that useful?

Comment: @Frisk19 Look at the second link in my answer. `path_xlsx = path_script.parent.joinpath('excel.xlsx')` `a.to_excel(path_xlsx)` Also look in `/Users/myname/Desktop` for you excel-file.

Comment: @durtal I reinstalled Anaconda and using the first approach (crontab -e) I solved. The new file (txt or xlsx) is in /Users/myname, not in the folder of python script but it is at least the output I expected. Now I will try again your workaround to try to save the new file in the correct folder. Many thanks, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @Durtal many thanks, your workaround worked and now I can see the new file in the correct folder.  You were right from the beginning!